# Saving focus state using GetFocusedElement() not working with user controls on a Panorama control

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-phone-7, navigation, state

I am trying to use the 'best practice' technique of using the

> FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()

in the **OnNavigatedFrom**  event and

> this.FindName

to locate the focused control in the **OnNavigatedTo** event.

I have a Panorama page and within each PanoramaItem I have a user control which in turn have many controls such as TextBox's etc..

The GetFocusedElement does retrieve the focused controls name in the user controls, but the FindName method then fails to find it on return! The name returned does not include any reference to the user control itself, so I am assuming the FindName does not traverse user controls!

Am I doing something wrong or does anyone know a way of easily improving this, or at least a simple technique for at least showing or navigating too the last PanoramaItem that was displayed before the app is deactivated?

Comment: What's the source of the 'best practice' technique you refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the selected panorama item when the page is navigated to use the `DefaultItem` property.

To determine what this should be, save the `SelectedItem` when navigating away from the page.

You should be doing this at the page level and accessing properties of the panorama. There should be no need to do anything in the controls hosted in a panoramaItem whether they are user controls or not.

If you wish to avoid the side effects of altering the defaultItem, you may want to have a look at http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/corrado/archive/2010/09/27/smartpanorama-a-panorama-control-extension.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Very handy tip. Interesting problem caused by using the DefaultItem! You would have thought they would have built in a set method on the SelectedItem poperty!